# Count 0 to 1000 as a image in javascript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my numbers :

[image]

I want to count 0 to 1,000 by image and put comma between them, for example `if number === 1 show 1.png` .
what's the best way to achive something like this ?

```
   $scope.number = 0;
    function countNumber(){
        if($scope.number >= 1000){
            return false;
        }else{
            $scope.number += 10;
        }

    }

    $interval(countNumber,100);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `ng-src` ?

Comment: i don't know how to use ng-src with this issue

Comment: Try this: `<img ng-src="{{myFunction()}}" />` and `$scope.myFunction=function(){return $scope.number+'.png'}`

Comment: Create an counter (interval) function that changes a scope variable which you drop in ng-src for the image source.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how? you've read the documentation, tried to implement it and failed? or haven't even read the documentation.

Comment: i didn't understand , when number is 100 , there is no image with this name : 100.png

Comment: This question is really lacking proper details. Please read [How to ask a  good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking to combine images of digits (`0.png`, `1.png`, `2.png`, etc.), not just output a single image (e.g. `1234.png`).

To do this, you'll need to put the images next to each other. For example:

```
// JS: list out digits
$scope.digits = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// HTML: repeat through digits and output the correct image
<img ng-repeat="d in digits" ng-src="{{'images/' + d + '.png'}}" />
```

I'll leave the breakdown of a number (e.g. `1234`) into its digits (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`) as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: like your answer , but i want to count it

Comment: @sani Just increment a number, split it into its digits, and use the example I showed.

Comment: i'll tell you, thanks for your time

Comment: $scope.digits = [];
    var number = 0;
    function countNumber(){
        if(number >= 1000000){
            return false;

        }else{
            number += 1;
            $scope.split = number.toString().split("");
            var res = number.toString().split(" ");
            $scope.digits.push(res)
            console.log($scope.digits);
        }

    }

    $interval(countNumber,1000);

Comment: i added this, and it's working but there is a problem , images just added i want to replace it with another

Comment: That's close! Instead of doing `$scope.digits.push(res)`, just do `$scope.digits = number.toString().split('')`. Right now, you're *adding* digits to the list of digits - you want to *replace* the digits instead, with the digits of the next number.

Comment: oh,you're right, thanks a million man

Comment: one more question , when number is 12 , the url is 12.png ? so it's not good

Comment: Because i got 9 images for 9 numbers

Comment: @sani Keep in mind that we're splitting the images into one image per digit. So for `12`, the code should be looking for `1.png` and `2.png`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to do them sequentially, rotating from one to the next, you could do this (assuming `$sce` and `ngSanitize` are available).

```
$scope.imgSrc = '';
$scope.number = 0;
function buildSource() {
    if ($scope.number >= 1000) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $scope.number += 10;
        $scope.imgSrc = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/path/to/' + '$scope.number.toString() + '.png');
    }
}

$interval(countNumber, 100);
```

Then in your view:

```
<img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}">
```

The real trick is using `$sce` to trust the URL you've built as a valid resource URL. Otherwise, Angular might not load in the source.

Editing to answer the full question as it wasn't particularly clear initially.

```
$scope.number = 0;
function buildSource() {
    if ($scope.number >= 1000) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $scope.number += 10;
        var images = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.number.toString(), function(value) {
            this.push($sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/path/to/' + value + '.png');
        }, images);

        /**
         * you'll need to work out the entirety 
         * of this logic on your own, 
         * but Array.prototype.splice will get you there 
         */
        images.length > 3 ? images.splice(1, 0, $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/path/to/comma.png')) : null; 
        $scope.images = images;
    }
}
$interval(buildSource, 100);
```

Then in your view:

```
<img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image}}">
```

Comment: suppose that i want to count to 20000 and want to show it like this : 20,000 , how can i add comma image between them ?

Comment: Are you expecting 10 to be not at `10.png`, but at `1.png` and `0.png`?

Comment: yes, images are like this : 1.png , 2.png , 3.png , etc

Comment: Then follow @Agop's advice in the other answer. You'll need to do an `ngRepeat` over the images in an array.

Comment: @sani, please specify all requirements in the question body.  This, for instance: "*how can i add comma image [as a thousands separator]?*" should be in the question,

Comment: how can i count with ng-repeat ?